# Android: How to put text underneath a Button?

Tags: android, button, android-layout

I have...

- PNG file for Background
- PNG file for Icon (drawableTop)
- Text I want to put underneath this Button

It's similar to a Menu Icon. How to do that? I only found following ways. Both of them arent very nice:

- Make two Buttons, one for Text one for the Picture
- The Background PNG File needs a transparent area at the bottom in the size of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*After some months of working with Android it's not that hard anymore.* You can set any View (ImageView, TextView, LinearLayout, RelativeLayout...) clickable.

So in this case I would go with a Relative- or LinearLayout. They also can use the same style, so the position of the icons are always the same.

Answer (score 0):

Set the text as the button text via the attribute `android:text`.  Use the `android:drawableTop` attribute to set an icon that will appear above the text.

Comment: but the background image shall be just behind the icon

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying.  That just sounds like a TextView below an ImageView.